# Web scraping overlay boxes

Tags: html, web-scraping

I want to scrape a grocery store ad like the "weekly ad" found [here](https://coupons.albertsons.com/weeklyad/?s=). 
Some of the information I want is available when inspecting the html of the elements, but the full details of what I want aren't visible until an individual item is clicked at which point an overlay box pops up, and the full details are visible in the html of the overlay box element.

Is there a way to fetch the text of the overlay box for each item in the ad without having to actually mimic clicking on each item? I have written such scripts with WebDriver and Sikuli years ago, but I'm thinking there must be a better way!

Is it possible to simulate clicking on every item simultaneously, then copying the html all at once?

I am open to any language or tool you might suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use JSoup with Java to explore the website without opening it. Few lines of script will get you what you want.

Comment: Would Jsoup be better than Scrapy?